# What does the "@" sign mean in ls -l output?

Tags: mac-osx, command-line-interface, ls

I have this output on MacOSX:

```
$ ls -l
total 40
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 levente  staff   52 30 Sep 15:38 pl
-rwxr-xr-x  1 levente  staff  675 14 Feb 17:07 plplay
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 levente  staff  662 26 Jan 14:13 plstart
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 levente  staff  296  1 Dec 11:50 plstop
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 levente  staff  268 29 Dec 18:44 plweb
```

What does the "@" mean next to the permissions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It means those files have Extended Attributes from the file system that aren't the normal Unix permissions. Try doing `xattr <file>` and see what sort of things are set.

Comment: Thanks, seems like TextMate had some properties on them: `com.macromates.caret`. Saving in MacVim cleared it.

Comment: `ls -l@` will also list the extended attributes.  Use `xattr -l` to see the xattr values as well as the just the attribute names.

Answer (score 6):

Kashani has it right on with use of `xattr` to display the extra fiddly bits. More specifically, on OSX, this is likely what is called the Resource Fork. The underlying filesystem that OSX uses, HFS+, has extra data segments that can store all manner of information. Incidentally, you can also see the same thing on SMB, NTFS, etc mounts in the form of ._FILENAME files.

For a full write up on Resource Forks see either the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork) or the [Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Resource_Manager/Reference/reference.html) site.

Comment: This is false, extended attributes are independent of the (now little-used) Resource Fork and tools like xattr that deal with one don't necessarily know anything about the other.